# insert a tuple if not exists a condition mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to write a query that inserts into a tuple if a condition is met.
e.g.

table r:

```
CREATE TABLE r(A INT, B INT)
```

table b:

```
CREATE TABLE b(C INT, D INT, E INT)
```

I want to insert tuple `(1,1)` into r if there is no tuple like `(1, 2, 2)` in b.

I tried this query but I get a syntax error:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM b WHERE C=1 AND D=2 AND E=2)
Begin
    INSERT INTO r VALUES(1, 1)
End
```

is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Are you doing this from a program?  Because it would be easy to do this as two queries from code.

Comment: @TimRoberts no, I'm not using any third-party language just SQL queries. (it's part of my homework)

Comment: As I read the documentation, flow control statements can only be used in stored procedures.  Have you covered stored procedures in your class yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below SQL query. In above post you are trying to use procedure but that is not the correct way; follow given link to know more about [procedure](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO r (A,B)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS A, 1 AS B) AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM b WHERE C=1 AND D=2 AND E=2
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
INSERT INTO r (A, B)
    SELECT 1, 1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE C = 1 AND D = 2 AND E = 2);
```